# Convert a list of values to a map<key, List<Object>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am a dataset which is as below:

Input: `List<Object>` where Object has below fields and data

```
from_status_desc from_id  to_status_desc  to_id
Complete            5        Consumed       8
Complete            5        Inventory      9
Complete            5        Broke-Inv      10
Complete            5        Hold           11
Complete            5        Broke          12
Consumed            8        Complete       5
Consumed            8        Inventory      9
Consumed            8        Broke-Inv      10
Consumed            8        Hold           11
Consumed            8        Broke-pmd      12
```

I want to convert this to a `Map<String, List<Object>>`, object here can be anything which would meet the requirement. The output should be in the below format:

```
from_status_desc from_id  to_status_desc  to_id
Complete    5   Consumed    8
                Inventory   9
                Broke-Inv   10
                Hold        11
                Broke       12
                
Consumed    8   Complete    5
                Inventory   9
                Broke-Inv   10
                Hold        11
                Broke-pmd   12
```

Basically, we need to group it by `from_status_desc` and `from_id` as key since these are unique and values would be a list of `to_status_desc` and `to_id` together.
How can this be achived using Java 8 streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.

Here is the source class.  A special `formatted()` method is created so as no to conflict with a `toString()` method.

```
class FromInfo {
    String from_status_desc;
    int from_id;
    String to_status_desc;
    int to_id;
    
    public FromInfo(String from_status_desc, int from_id,
            String to_status_desc, int to_id) {
        this.from_status_desc = from_status_desc;
        this.from_id = from_id;
        this.to_status_desc = to_status_desc;
        this.to_id = to_id;
    }
    
    public String getFrom_status_desc() {
        return from_status_desc;
    }
    
    public int getFrom_id() {
        return from_id;
    }
    
    public String getTo_status_desc() {
        return to_status_desc;
    }
    
    public int getTo_id() {
        return to_id;
    }
    public String formatted() {
        return "%-8s  %-3s".formatted(
                getFrom_status_desc(),
                getFrom_id());
    }
}
```

Now create a destination class to hold the extracted object info.  It takes the original class as a constructor argument to extract the required values. It uses `toString` for the final format.

```
class ToInfo {
     private FromInfo fromInfo;
     private ToInfo(FromInfo fromInfo) {
         this.fromInfo = fromInfo;
     }
     @Override 
     public String toString() {
         return "%-10s %s".formatted(fromInfo.getTo_status_desc(),fromInfo.getTo_id());
     }
    
}
```

The data

```
List.of(new FromInfo("Complete", 5, "Consumed", 8),
        new FromInfo("Complete", 5, "Inventory", 9),
        new FromInfo("Complete", 5, "Broke-Inv", 10),
        new FromInfo("Complete", 5, "Hold", 11),
        new FromInfo("Complete", 5, "Broke", 12),
        new FromInfo("Consumed", 8, "Complete", 5),
        new FromInfo("Consumed", 8, "Inventory", 9),
        new FromInfo("Consumed", 8, "Broke-Inv", 10),
        new FromInfo("Consumed", 8, "Hold", 11),
        new FromInfo("Consumed", 8, "Broke-pmd", 12));
```

The solution

- use grouping by:

  - the key is the output from the `formatted()` method of the source class
  - the value is a mapped list which creates a ToInfo class taking the FromInfo object as a constructor argument.

```
Map<String, List<ToInfo>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FromInfo::formatted,
                Collectors.mapping(ToInfo::new, Collectors.toList())));
```

now display the information.

```
map.forEach((k,v)-> {
              System.out.println(k + " " + v.get(0));
              for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {            
                  System.out.println(" ".repeat(k.length()+1) + v.get(i));
              }
              System.out.println();
```

prints

```
Consumed  8   Complete   5
              Inventory  9
              Broke-Inv  10
              Hold       11
              Broke-pmd  12

Complete  5   Consumed   8
              Inventory  9
              Broke-Inv  10
              Hold       11
              Broke      12
```

Note:  Order is unpredictable in a map so the first column may be in a different order.  This can be solved by selectively printing the values using a list of ordered keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use collectors.groupingBy in the collect of stream(). Which will group by your required attribute and get you a Map<, List>.

Please refer below for example. Also make sure the attr will not be null. if it is null it would end in an exception. So you can either filter out null attr objects in stream and create map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        var obj = new Txn();
        obj.status = "consumed";
        obj.id = "1";

        var obj1 = new Txn();
        obj1.status = "consumed";
        obj1.id = "2";
        var obj2 = new Txn();
        obj2.status = "complete";
        obj2.id = "3";
        List<Txn> objs = List.of(obj, obj1, obj2);

        Map<String, List<Txn>> map = objs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (e.status)));

        System.out.println(map);

    }
```

```
class Txn{
    String status;
    String id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is your list
List<StatusBO> objList;
// you can use java8 stream 
Map<String,List<StatusBO>> result = objList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StatusBO::getFromId));
```